# What's state of the art to (down)load an image by javascript into a variable or object to further work on the data (in Firefox 30)?

Tags: javascript, php, image, download

I'm writing on an interface-website, where small and big images are loaded from another website.
I already implemented that a couple of years ago using a now outdated Firefox-version.
Back then I first tried an xmlhttprequest to load the image-data, and then using Javascript passed the image data to Firefox's internal filewriting-instances to write them locally on my harddisk.
As the xmlhttprequest didn't work for big images, I then used for loading the image data another Firefox-internal instance that was accessible by Javascript in this old Firefox-version. With current Firefox versions all this is not possible anymore with pure Javascript.

My questions now are:

1. **What is the state of the art way with the latest Javascript de-facto standard to load image data into a Javascript variable (or image object)?  (Blobs? octets? Multipart? new image()? user-defined?)**
   As some of the images are so big I really want to implement a progress function in my interface. So that's necessary whatever way I take.
   And I just don't want to reprogram the whole thing in a couple of months, so I'm looking for a recommended way to implement the download, in hope that these functions will be stable for a while.
2. Different from some years ago I now access with my Javascript via xmlhttprequest locally running PHP-files (apache & php) to write to and read from my local harddisk. (My interface is loaded from "http://mylocaldomain.local/interface.html". This makes a couple of things easier anyway.)
   So my 2nd question is: **Could I use a xmlhttprequest to a .php-script to download the images, *so that I somehow could access and show info of the progress (like "1.432.234 Bytes loaded of 3.213.324 Bytes") within my interface?***
   (Though I would clearly prefer to (down)load the data by a Javascript method along question 1.)

Greetings